# How to reference already existing Azure Portal created storage accounts in an ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

I want to create a function app with ARM template such that the ARM template references already existing storage accounts (**inputstgdev** and **outputstgdev**) which I have already parameterized. I would like the ARM template to use the **inputstgdev** storage account as its attached storage account such that it does not have to create a new storage account. The source control of the function app is referenced to a Gitrepo which I have also parameterized in the ARM template. Each time I run the ARM template I get the following error message

***##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource '/subscriptions/bea8ac84-24a4-4e53-9198-e3b0107547d4/resourceGroups/dev-rgp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/functionapp/sourcecontrols/web' at line '1' and column '3069' doesn't depend on parent resource '/subscriptions/bea8ac84-24a4-4e53-9198-e3b0107547d4/resourceGroups/dev-rgp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/functionapp'. Please add dependency explicitly using the 'dependsOn' syntax. Please see aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for***

Any suggestions what the issue might be or possible solutions. 
I look forward to your response

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "InputstorageAccount": {
        "defaultValue": "inputstgdev",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "GitrepoBranch": {
       "type": "string",
       "defaultValue": "master",
       "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the branch to use when deploying (Default = master)."
        }
    },
    "GitrepoURL": {
       "type": "string",
       "defaultValue": "https://github.com/FBoucher/AzUnzipEverything.git",
       "metadata": {
            "description": "URL to repo (Default = master)."
        }
    },
    "InputcontainerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "inputcontainer",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the name of the blob container."
      }
    },
    "OutputstorageAccount": {
        "defaultValue": "outputstgdev",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "OutputcontainerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "outputcontainer",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the name of the blob container."
      }
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('InputstorageAccount'), '/default/', parameters('InputcontainerName'))]",
        "properties": {
            "publicAccess": "None"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('OutputstorageAccount'), '/default/', parameters('OutputcontainerName'))]",
        "properties": {
            "publicAccess": "None"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "serviceplan",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "F1",
            "capacity": 1
        },
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "serviceplan"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "serviceplan"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "functionapp",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 'serviceplan')]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('InputstorageAccount'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 'serviceplan')]",
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('InputstorageAccount'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(parameters('InputcontainerName'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('InputstorageAccount'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(parameters('InputcontainerName'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('InputstorageAccount'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(parameters('InputcontainerName'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                        "value": "[toLower('functionapp')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                        "value": "~2"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                        "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', 'applicationInsightsName'), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                        "value": "dotnet"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "resources":[
            {
                "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                "name": "web",
                "type": "sourcecontrols",
                "dependsOn": [
                  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('InputstorageAccount'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "RepoUrl": "[parameters('GitrepoURL')]",
                    "branch": "[parameters('GitrepoBranch')]",
                    "publishRunbook": true,
                    "IsManualIntegration": true
                }
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

}

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You encountered this error message due to the wrong dependency.

You should use `"[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'functionapp')]"` instead of `"[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('InputstorageAccount'))]"`.

And you should delete the storage dependency.

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('InputstorageAccount'))]"
```

By the way, as you already have a storage account, you just need to paste your connection string in the value of **AzureWebJobsStorage** and **AzureWebJobsDashboard**.

Just like

```
{
    "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
    "value": "{connectionstring}"
}
```